# Fit imageview to the scrollview size

Tags: android, resize, imageview, scrollview, horizontalscrollview

I have an HorizontalScrollView with 2 Imageview. The HorizontalScrollView is embedded in a ScrollView.
I would like that if the picture is too big (width and/or height) to fit, it will be cropped to the size of the ScrollView (not the screen size).
If it is smaller, no change.

My xml :

```
<ScrollView android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/headerappview"
    android:layout_above="@id/bottomBar"
    android:background="@color/white">

    <HorizontalScrollView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtAdditionalContent"
        android:id="@+id/hscrollview"
        android:paddingBottom="22px"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_vertical" android:layout_width="wrap_content">

            <ImageView android:id="@+id/img2" android:src="@drawable/icon"
                android:paddingRight="25px"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:cropToPadding="true" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"></ImageView>

            <ImageView android:id="@+id/img3" android:src="@drawable/icon"
                android:cropToPadding="true"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content">
            </ImageView>
        </LinearLayout>

    </HorizontalScrollView>

</ScrollView>
```

(Sorry for my poor english)

Answer (score 1):

Can you please let us know whether you would like to crop the image or scale the image ?

If you wish just to scale the large image and make it fit then set,

```
android:cropToPadding="false"
```

More about ImageView is [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html)

Comment: Yes I want the picture to be scaled. However my picture keeps the same size with/without this parameter

Answer (score 1):

Please add fadingEdge and fillViewport to scrollview and HorizontalScrollView

```
<ScrollView 
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"      
      android:fillViewport="true"
      android:fadingEdge="none"
      android:background="@drawable/bg_app" >
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```xml
<ImageView android:id="@+id/img3" android:src="@drawable/icon"
    android:scaleType="centercrop"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content">
</ImageView>
```